# Android client not sending complete messages

Tags: java, python, android, sockets

I have a simple server in Python and a client in Java. When I click on the "Send" button on the Android application, it sends the content of an EditText, and the Python server prints out the message it just received. Unfortunately, most of the time, the server only prints out the first letter of the message. Sometimes it prints the full message, but that happens quite rarely.

Here is the code of the client:

```
btn_send.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
            @Override
            public void onClick(View v) {
                final String msg = msg_input.getText().toString();
                msg_input.setText("");

                Thread t_send = new Thread() {
                    @Override
                    public void run() {
                        try {
                            final Socket s = new Socket("public_ip_of_the_server", port);

                            DataOutputStream dos = new DataOutputStream(s.getOutputStream());
                            dos.writeBytes(msg);

                            DataInputStream dis = new DataInputStream(s.getInputStream());
                            InputStreamReader disR = new InputStreamReader(dis);
                            BufferedReader br = new BufferedReader(disR);

                            messages.setText(messages.getText().toString() + "\n\n" + br.toString());

                            s.close();
                            dos.close();
                        } catch (IOException err) {
                            err.printStackTrace();
                        }
                    }
                };
                t_send.start();
            }
});
```

And here is the code of the server:

```
s = socket.socket(socket.AF_INET, socket.SOCK_STREAM)
s.bind((socket.gethostname(), port))
s.listen(5)

while True:
    clientsocket = s.accept()
    msg = clientsocket.recv(128).decode('utf-8')
    print(msg)
    clientsocket.close()
```

Thanks for reading!

Comment: Messages can be fragmented and you are closing the socket right after receiving the first fragment.

Comment: I close the socket because I want the application to exit properly. How can I prevent the message from being fragmented ?

Comment: You should always expect fragments. That's how networks work.

Comment: Then why does the server receive the full message sometimes ?

Comment: This is not the right place to go through all the TCP/IP basics. It's a fact that data can and (when larger) will be transmitted in fragments. Additionally the client can send it in multiple packets already. You application hast to be able to handle that.